# What should be done about this question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/697816/how-on-earth-can-a-solid-state-relay-be-constructed) was asked a few days ago, got a few answers (including one by me), and then closed.

I don't dispute its closing, I considered voting to close myself before answering.

But the question was then later edited into an *entirely* different question (from "is there a solid-state equivalent to a relay" to "how do solid-state relays work"), invalidating existing answers, and reopened. Ordinarily, that would be cause to revert the edit and tell the asker to ask a new question, but now there are new answers that answer the new question, so a reversion would *itself* be an edit that invalidates existing answers, so.... what do we do in this situation?

Personally, I don't think the question should have been reopened--I think the asker should have been encouraged to make a new question instead. But there's nothing that can be done about that now, so what *should* be done?

Answer (score 7):

You have a number of choices.

**You could roll back the question**
This feels like a bad approach.  The edited question makes much more sense than the first version.  You might start a rollback war

**You can do nothing**

**You can delete your answer**
If you for some reason, can't delete it, you can ask a mod for help, and they can super-delete it or some such.

**You can edit your answer**
You can add a caveat that your answer is responsive to the original question.  Additionally, if text in the original question isn't apparent in the current version, you can insert the relevant original text in your answer by finding it in the edit history.

I'd go with one of the last three.

I don't see any point in deleting the question and posting it as a new question.

Comment: I'll second the last recommendation in the list, to edit the answer to reflect the changes to the question. Fortunately this sort of thing seems rather rare.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for looking after the site and questions like this.

I don't think original question in the OP changed enough to warrant a new question, and not much of the original content did, so rolling back would not be a great thing. And I don't think it invalidated the answers that were already there but maybe some updating could be used.